# cabal: how to add text file as a build dependency

Tags: haskell, cabal

I use a simple text file to generate some code with TemplateHaskell and runIO.

```
...    
curdir <- runIO $ getCurrentDirectory
addDependentFile $ curdir ++ "/spec.txt"
bs <- runIO $ BS.readFile "spec.txt"
...
```

Everything works great when used with ghci. The problem is that cabal has no idea I need that file for building, and I get this when I do `cabal build`.

```
Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
  spec.txt: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: If you ship `spec.txt`, you can use the `extra-source-files` field to make `cabal` include the file in the tarball.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of extra-source-files. It helps for sdist, but not for building.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at flag data-files:

http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code

by the way, I recommend EclipseFP for your jobs. It provide a convenient way to edit cabal file.
that's why i can find that flag.
It really reduce trivial works.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_IDE#EclipseFP_plugin_for_Eclipse_IDE

=============================================================================

sorry for misunderstanding.

I think cabal doesn't really matter here. ghc runs **openFile** at compile-time.

that means openFile is still runned at another "run-time" to produce code.

the "run-time" result is just can't find the file

maybe the current directory is not as you think.

try to use **setCurrentDirectory** or show **curdir** and check it before **getCurrentDirectory**

if it doesn't work. please show whole code for testing

Comment: data-files is for *run-time*, I need file to be available in *compile-time*.